# Calculation of maximum floating point error

Tags: math, floating-point, libm

`pow(x,y)` is computed as `e^(y*log(x))`
Generally math libraries compute `log(x)` in quad precision (which is time consuming) in order to avoid loss of precision when computing `y*log(x)` as precision errors will magnify in the computation of `e^(y*log(x))`.
Now, in case I would want to compute `pow(x,y)` in the following steps.

```
double pow(double x,double y) {
   return exp(y*log(x)); // Without any quad precision multiplication
}
```

What would be the maximum ULP error of this function. I do know that IEEE-754 standard says that any floating point operation should have less than 0.5 ULP error i.e `0.5*2^(-52)`.
So if my operation `y*log(x)` suffers from a 0.5 ULP error, how do I compute the largest possible ULP error for `e^(y*log(x))`

---

Agreed that the computation of `pow(x,y)` is fairly complicated. Algorithms generally compute `log(x)` in a higher precision and the multiplication between `y` and `log(x)` is not straightforward. Since the ULP error depends on `y*log(x)`, the maximum error would be for the largest value of `Y*log(x)` for which `e^(y*log(x))` is not infinity. Right? How do I compute the number of ULP for such a case? What are the maximum number of bits of the mantissa in the double precision format that would vary form the actual value in case of the largest value of `y*log(x)` ?

---

Updated the question. Thanks for all the help!

So a 10 bit difference would result in how much ULP error? I calculated it as,

```
    ULP = (actual - computed)/ 2^(e-(p-1))
```

where e is the exponent of the actual number, p=53 for double precision. I read that I ULP = 2^(e-(p-1))
Let's assume,

```
    Actual = 1.79282279439444787915898270592 *10^308
    Computed = 1.79282279439451553814547593293 * 10^308 
    error= actual - computed = 6.7659e+294
```

Now

```
1 ULP = 2^(e- (p-1)) 
e = 1023 (exponent of the actual number - bias)
1 ULP = 2^(1023 - (53-1)) = 2^971
ULP error = error/ 1 ULP = 339
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Exponential functions convert an absolute error into a percentage error, so the ULP error in `pow` depends on the value of `y log x`.

Comment: The statements in the question about `pow` are not generally true. Implementations of `pow` are fairly complicated and typically involve extra precision (to avoid loss of accuracy, not loss of precision), but the extra precision is often obtained by careful work with multiple floating-point or integer objects, not by “quad precision.” Additionally, the computation is not as simple as e^(*y*•log(*x*)). Aside from partitioning the problem into various cases, the exponent and significand of *x* are often separated.

Comment: Note that the errors in `y*log(x)` are not limited to ½ ULP, as it consists of two operations—taking a logarithm and performing a multiplication.

Comment: The limit on the error in IEEE-754 elementary operations in round-to-nearest-ties-to-even mode is less than or equal to ½ ULP, not less than ½ ULP. The latter is impossible, as a mathematical result that is exactly midway between two representable values cannot be rounded with less than ½ ULP error.

Comment: Agreed that the computation of pow(x,y) is fairly complicated. Algorithms generally compute log(x) in a higher precision and the multiplication between y and log(x) is not straightforward.

Comment: Have updated the post. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have time for a fuller answer now, but here is something to start:

Suppose the error in each individual operation—`exp`, `*`, and `log`—is at most ½ ULP. This means the computed value of `log(x)` is exactly log(*x*)•(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>) for some *e*<sub>0</sub> satisfying -/2 ≤ *e*<sub>0</sub> ≤ /2, where  is ULP of 1 (2<sup>−52</sup> IEEE-754 basic 64-bit binary format). And the computed value of `y*log(x)` is exactly *y*•log(*x*)•(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>) for some -/2 ≤ *e*<sub>0</sub> ≤ /2 and some -/2 ≤ *e*<sub>1</sub> ≤ /2. And the computed value of `exp(y*log(x))` is exactly e<sup>*y*•log(*x*)•(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>)</sup>•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>) for some -/2 ≤ *e*<sub>0</sub>, *e*<sub>1</sub>, *e*<sub>2</sub> ≤ /2. And the error is of course e<sup>*y*•log(*x*)•(1+*e*<sub>0</sub>)•(1+*e*<sub>1</sub>)</sup>•(1+*e*<sub>2</sub>) − e<sup>*y*•log(*x*)</sup>.

Then you can start analyzing that expression for maximum and minimum values over the possible values of *e*<sub>0</sub>, *e*<sub>1</sub>, and *e*<sub>2</sub>. If 0 < *y* and 1 < *x*, the greatest error occurs when *e*<sub>0</sub> = *e*<sub>1</sub> = *e*<sub>2</sub> = /2.

Note that common implementations of `exp` and `log` are not usually correctly rounded. Errors of several ULP may be common. So you should not assume a ½ ULP bound unless the routine is documented to be correctly rounded.

Answer (score 0):

> maximum floating point error (for `exp(y*log(x))`)

**x == 0**

The error is infinite;

**x < 0**

OP's `pow()` fails, yet when `y` has no fraction part, it should complete.

**x > 0**

Let `z = y*log(x)`.  The error in that calculation may be quite reasonable - just a few [ULPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) or less.  Let us assume 1 ULP or perhaps `z_error = z*`2<sup>-53</sup> given the usual [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Yet consider its impact: `exp(z + error_z) = exp(z)*exp(error_z)`.

With `z` about 710, `exp(709.78)` is about `DBL_MAX`, so let us consider that as much larger values result in infinity with OP's `pow()`.

`exp(some_small_value)` is about `1 + some_small_value`.  `exp(error_z)` is then `1 + 710*pow(2,-53)`.  Thus the final `pow()` can lose about `log2(710)` or 9, 10 plus a few bits of precision.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So a 10 bit difference would result in how much ULP error? I calculated it as, ULP = (actual - computed)/ 2^(e-(p-1)) where e is the exponent of the actual number, p=53 for double precision. I read that I ULP = 2^(e-(p-1)).Is this valid?

Comment: "10 bit difference would result in how much ULP error" --> 1024(or 512)*ULP or so.  [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) is independent of "computed".  It is a property of the format.  1 ULP = 2^(e-(p-1)) is about right, yet alternatives exist.  A simple 1 ULP = difference between one FP number and the next.  Corner cases include: when ULP via "next up" and "next down" differ, 0.0, sub-normals and `DBL_MAX`. Deeper: [On the definition of ulp (x)](http://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Carine.Lucas/TPScilab/JMMuller/ulp-toms.pdf).